# How can I schedule a recurring task to run at specific intervals in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire, recurring-events

I would like to set up a task to execute at regular intervals, such as every hour, in C#. How can I accomplish this?

**Update:**

Thank you for the assistance. After conducting some research, I discovered that I can achieve recurring jobs by utilizing Hangfire. This approach eliminates the need for a Windows Service or a separate process and is remarkably straightforward to implement. If anyone is encountering a similar issue, I recommend giving it a try.

Hangfire Documentation: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: See this question: [Write a recurring task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600906/2791540)

Comment: This one for windows application, I need a solution for web app.

Comment: You are going to have a browser window open all the time so your web app runs? It sounds like you need to go about this a different way, but if you need to do this then you need to use javascript's `setInterval` with `fetch` - e.g. `setInterval(() => fetch("..."), 3600000)`

Comment: @AliZedan The idea is you write a windows application that calls the web service. Do you have a requirement that this call has to come from somewhere specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a background task that runs as a hosted service, see the following [example at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Summary:

- Add your background task where you configure your services (dependency injection), e.g. `services.AddHostedService<MyDataFetcher>();`
- Implement the MyDataFetcher class, and make it inherit from IHostedService and IDisposable, e.g.: `public class MyDataFetcher : IHostedService, IDisposable`
- Ensure your service is always on (and not put to sleep when not in use)